# Using jsPlumb with WebComponents.js polyfill

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, web-component, jsplumb

I'm trying to use jsPlumb with ReactJS and WebComponents.js (for custom elements). I'm using 'makeSource' and 'makeTarget' methods of jsPlumb since I would like to draw lines between two fields.

The drag and drop functionality is not working in Firefox and IE(v11) but works fine in Chrome. Our tech stack: React(15.0.1), WebComponents, Webpack & jsPlumb(v2.0.7).

Anyone has tried to use jsPlumb with WebComponents ?

EDIT:
jsFiddle link. Open in FF, IE and Chrome - It works well in chrome but not in the others. `Code` https://jsfiddle.net/aleem86s/gpemwumh/8/

Comment: is there an error in the console?

Comment: Unfortunately No, there isn't any error in the console